# Am I obligated to pay prorated insurance premium if broker renewed without my agreement?

Tags: canada, insurance, british-columbia

My home insurance broker sent us a renewal email over a month late. I told them we were not interested, and were changing providers.

They want payment for the time between our previous policy with them expiring and the official cancellation.

I can find no mention of auto renewal in our previous policies. Additionally, the provider, coverage and premiums were all changed without our knowledge.

I am in BC, Canada. Am I obligated to pay them?

Comment: Have you contacted your insurer directly?  If you can show them that you purchased another policy that took effect when their policy was supposed to lapse you should be able to get a refund.

Comment: In the U.S., at least one of the major insurance companies had policies in place to allow you to cancel your policy retrospectively months into your coverage and give you a full refund — provided it did not need to be used. Not sure about the number of months.

Comment: This may also depend on the details of your contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I obligated to pay prorated insurance premium if broker renewed without my agreement?

No, since you did not agree to auto-renewals either. The broker's unilateral change of the terms and conditions further violates the contract law tenet of the [meeting of the minds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meeting_of_the_minds).

Even in the unlikely event that BC statutes allow auto-renewals, from the standpoint of consumer protection it seems that the underwriter/broker would still have some obligation to inform the client about them, including the required steps in order to prevent their policy[-ies] from renewing automatically.

Comment: Downvoters really should show at least a bit of effort and articulate why they think the answer is wrong. Otherwise this pattern of downvoting is looking like some sort of fixation.